# Getting an error with filtering property in Get outlook Mail Message

Tags: vb.net, uipath-studio

I am getting this error message in a UIPath statement:

> Get Outlook Mail Messages: Cannot parse condition. Error at "@SQL=(("http://schemas.microsoft.com/map...".

This is my code:

```
"@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" like '%asean prs%' AND [Received] >= '" + DateTime.Today.ToString("d") + " 00:00AM'"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use that long URL string as the name of a field. That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think a string can be "bigger than or equal to" (>=) another string. It can either be equal (=) or not equal (<>). The length of the string can be greater, but not the string itself.

Also, there might be something wrong with your use of apostrophies, single and double quote marks.